# How do I treat all function arguments as strings?

Tags: javascript, string, parameter-passing

I have this function:

```
function read(x) {
  console.log("You typed: " + x);
}
```

If I run `read("Hello")` in the console, I get:

> You typed: Hello;

But if I run `read(Hello)`, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Hello is not defined

I modified the function this way:

```
function read(x) {
  console.log("You typed: " + x.toString());
}
```

but no success.

So, I want to treat the function argument as a string, regardless of how the user inputs it. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Nvm, sugar.js isn't what I thought it was. There may be some preprocessor available that does what you're looking for, but again, way too much work for that little of benefit.

Comment: It should be noted that what they're asking isn't completely ridiculous like some people seem to be suggesting; it just isn't available in JS. In Clojure this is easy: ``(defmacro read [s] `(println ~(str s)))``, `(read hello)` prints `hello`, but that's because Clojure has macro support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The language syntax is just designed this way, so if you write `read(Hello)` it will look for a variable named `Hello`. This doesn't exist, hence the error.

If you want to pass a string, you'll need to quote it (or assign it to a variable, then pass the variable). There's no way around that.

Comment: "There's no way around that." - it can't be called "way around" at all. It's just a variable.

Comment: No way around quoting your string literals, I meant.

Comment: I think his trouble is that he can't distinguish variables from values.

Answer (score 1):

Please read few basic of coding before getting deeper into programing.

When you called `read` like:

```
read("Hello");
```

Value was passed to `read` function. However on calling like:

```
read(Hello);
```

This is calling `read` function with value of variable `Hello` and `Hello` is never declared.

**ReferenceError**: The [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

Value can be string, number, Boolean, and array, object.

```
read(5);
read(true);
read('a');
```

These all are values.

```
var a = 55;
var b = 'Hello';
var c = false;

read(a); // Passing value of a variable
read(b); // Passing value of b variable
read(c); // Passing value of c variable
```

**variables**: You use [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.

Answer (score 0):

When a user inputs a string it will be passed as a string. For example:

```
var str = "Hello";
read(str); // will print "You typed: Hello"
```

In other words, when you input a string, let's say via console, you don't have to put it into quotes. But when you set a string value to your variable in code you do have put it in quotes.

But what you are trying to do with this `read(Hello)` is to pass a variable named `Hello` which doesn't even exist in this context. To fix it you can write this:

```
var Hello = "Hello";
read(Hello); // will print "You typed: Hello"
```

and it will work just fine.